# Where to find historical locations of North Atlantic Tracks?

Tags: datasets, notam, transatlantic, nat

I'm looking for historical, daily locations of the North Atlantic Track (NAT, published daily as NOTAM) system for the past 10/20 years.  I've already contacted what feels like dozens of organizations (FAA, Gander, Shanwick, ...) but no-one seems to actually archive the NAT locations.

I'd be extremely grateful for any pointers towards possibilities to acquire these data, be it free or paying.

Comment: Did you check this site http://notams.aim.faa.gov/notamSearch/

Comment: @D_S thanks for the pointer; however, I cannot seem to be able to find NAT advisories using their search form ...

Answer (score 8):

[This guy](http://blackswan.ch/nat/) has a 365 day history online.

You could contact him for older values.

You can also get [some history](https://web.archive.org/web/20140828071417/https://www.notams.faa.gov/common/nat.html) using Archive.org.